# Ansible extra unquoted colon error

Tags: python, yaml, ansible

Hi I am following the tutorial here https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/ansible/ansible-cfg-template-p2.html

my site.yml

```
---
- name: Generate router configuration files
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - router
```

my tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: Generate configuration files
  template: src=router.j2 dest=/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/RTR-TEMPLATE/{{item.hostname}}.txt
  with_items: testconfig
```

my template (router.j2)

```
    no service pad
service tcp-keepalives-in
service tcp-keepalives-out
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service password-encryption
!
hostname {{item.hostname}}
{{item.example}}

!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
logging buffered 32000
no logging console
```

my var(main.yml)

```
---
testconfig:
 -{hostname: router123, example: no ip cef}
```

When I run this I get the following output, I think there is a problem with the var formatting. I am unsure how to fix it

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/RTR-TEMPLATE/roles/router/vars/main.yml
```

Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 3, column 32

testconfig:
 -{hostname: router123, example: no ip cef}
                               ^
    This one looks easy to fix.  There seems to be an extra unquoted colon in the line
    and this is confusing the parser. It was only expecting to find one free
    colon. The solution is just add some quotes around the colon, or quote the
    entire line after the first colon.

```
For instance, if the original line was:

    copy: src=file.txt dest=/path/filename:with_colon.txt

It can be written as:

    copy: src=file.txt dest='/path/filename:with_colon.txt'

Or:

    copy: 'src=file.txt dest=/path/filename:with_colon.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a space between dash and {. Just guessing.

```
 - {hostname: router123, example: no ip cef}
```

Comment: Thankyou man,simple stuff.

Comment: One more thing do you know how I can pass a custom variable via the CLI to replace the hostname. If I pass variable I want it to replace the hostname else leave it as router123

Comment: Use `--extra-vars` in ansible-playbook to pass a variable. If you need a code snippet, I can post it tomorrow.